# How can I fix a "Too many Portals" error message?

Tags: wii-u, skylanders-swap-force

I have the Wii version of Skylanders Swap Force and a Wii U system.  The portal, connected to the Wii U by USB, is not working. I am getting a "Too many portals" message when I try to connect. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You can only have one portal plugged in at once. Disconnect the portal of an older version of the game and just leave the swap force portal connected.  The swap force portal will work fine with giants and spryros adventure, so the others can be removed.  If you just had the spyros adventure portal before, it can be easy to not think its plugged in as it has the small usb wireless dongle, not a full lead like the giants and swap force portal.